# How to remove one of two images on a button?

Tags: html, css, image, button

At my company we use a survey software/platform which offers some layout templates. The platform allows for CSS modifications and I'm trying remove an image that is displayed on a button. The problem is that this button displays two images simultaneously and if I try to remove one image the other disappears to.

Here you can see a gray button with small oblique lines across it and a white reversed arrow. I want to remove the oblique lines but keep the white arrow.

[image]

I tried the following code below. But this removes the arrow, not the grey lines.

/**Previous button design: */

```
.navigation .previous-area .previous-button {
    background-image: none;
}
```

I think this might be the HTML but I'm not sure:

```
<div class="previous-area">
    <input type="submit" class="previous-button" name="previous" value="Föregående">
</div>
```

In case this might be helpful:
• The url to the grey lines is:
    url("/images/themes/24/strip.png”)
• The button color should be the color: #666666

I wish to keep the grey box (with rounded corners) without the grey lines but still with the white arrow.

Comment: Look at the element (which may not be a button) in your browser's document inspector (right-click, inspect). Post the CSS rules that apply the images you describe.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I solved it using this: div.navigation .previous-area {
  background: none;
  background-color: #666666;
}